# Text from Array in textView (which is in a TableCell)

Tags: swift

I have a UITableView which passes Data (Image and Label) from the Cell to a DetailViewController. This works fine for all 20 Cells I have!

But now I tries to create an array which gives me a "Comm1Description" and "Comm1Description" (just simple text from "arr2") in my DetailViewController. Comm1Description for Cell1, Comm2Description for Cell2 etc.

**This is my code**

```
import UIKit

 class WCommanderController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tbl: UITableView!

var arr = ["Commander1", "Commander2"]
var arr2 = ["Comm1Description", "Comm2Description"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}

extension WCommanderController: UITableViewDataSource,   UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arr.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 130
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? DataTableViewCell
    cell?.img.image = UIImage(named: arr[indexPath.row])
    cell?.lbl.text = arr[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController
    vc?.str = arr[indexPath.row]
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)

   }
 }
```

Comment: I unable to catch your question.. Please explain

Comment: I just want to make a description in a textView for Command1 in 1 Row and a description in a textView for Commander2 in the next Row. Which is the simple command which  I can use to catch the data from "arr2" for the values in "arr" ...sorry for my English, hope you understand now...thx

Comment: You have to enter a text one by one in TextView?

Comment: Yes, for each Image in each cell...a description in a textView for each image in each cell

Comment: When I click on Commander1 I get the Image of Commander1 and the Name "Commander1" in a new tableview. The same for Commander2 etc. But now I want to have for each Commander (Commander1,Commander2 etc.) a Description in a Textview for each Cell...sorry for my English, hope you understand now...

Answer (score -1):

If you have a textview in your tablecells, then this can be done.

```
let dictionary1 = ["KeyCommander": "Commander1", "KeyDescription": "Comm1Description1", "KeyTextField": "TextField1"]

let dictionary2 = ["KeyCommander": "Commander2", "KeyDescription": "Comm1Description2", "KeyTextField": "TextField2"]
```

Now, make your array as a var.

```
var array = [dictionary1, dictionary2]
```

On CellForRowAtIndex, give textfield a tag.

```
 array[textfield.tag]["KeyTextField"] = "Typed Value"
```

Comment: I Try it..Thanks Man!

Comment: Hey, i dont have a textView in my Cell. I just want to create a new textView in my detailViewController (i placed it in my Storyboard) when i click on my Cell. And i want different Textviews for each cell i click.... any Ideas? Thanks and merry christmas!